# Dependency in Github action to installed sdk

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I have created a github action to build and release artifacts. Since there is an existing dependency to a specific ndk version this must be installed on the build node.

I have added the build step `create/Install NDK` but this does not get called before `apk/build debug APK`. When I added `needs: build` the build step is executed before running `create` but the updated ndk is not installed when gradle is executed.

```
  apk:
    name: Generate APK
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    needs: build
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
```

It works to replace the build script with `run: ( echo "y" | sudo /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "ndk;20.0.5594570" --sdk_root=${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT} ) && bash ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace`:

```
name: Android Release

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'CUST*'
jobs:
  create:
    name: Create Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8

    - name: Install NDK
      run: echo "y" | sudo /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "ndk;20.0.5594570" --sdk_root=${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT}

  apk:
    name: Generate APK
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Build debug APK
        run: ( echo "y" | sudo /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --install "ndk;20.0.5594570" --sdk_root=${ANDROID_SDK_ROOT} ) && bash ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
      - name: PackRelease
        run: |
           zip CustSignalDebug_universal.zip --junk-paths  app/build/outputs/apk/play/debug      - name: Upload APK univeral
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: CustSignalDebug_universal.zip
          path: CustSignalDebug_universal.zip
```

This solution is not very refined and I would like to replace it with something more robust and maintainable. Is there a way in YAML to use `needs:` clause to install the prerequisites on the node which will execute the build step?